# How to drop columns based on the max value in each row

Tags: r

```
Col1<-c(3,8,2,4,2)
Col2<-c(3,7,3,9,2)
Col3<-c(5,7,5,7,5)
Col4<-c(1,9,2,3,4)
Col5<-c(1,2,6,7,5)
Toy<-data.frame(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5)

> Toy
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1    3    3    5    1    1
2    8    7    7    9    2
3    2    3    5    2    6
4    4    9    7    3    7
5    2    2    5    4    5
```

Given the above data frame, I would like to remove values in each row that are equal to the max value per row, as well as occur to the right (or increasing column #) of the max value.

Logically, the statement would be:

```
1. Find max value per row 
2. Make max value for each row = NA
3. Make all columns to the right of column with max value =NA
```

so the new data frame would look like

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1    3    3    NA   NA  NA
2    8    7    7    NA  NA
3    2    3    5    2   NA
4    4    NA   NA   NA  NA
5    2    2    NA   NA  NA
```

Steps

Comment: Sorry, but as it is I don't think this is a very good question. If you read through the provided solutions [to your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449377/simple-use-of-if-and-for) and tried to understand the logic behind why they were chosen, you'll see that [Josh O'Brien's great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12453666/1270695) could have very easily been derived from another answer to your previous question.

Comment: Agreed. I was unaware of the "which.max" command before I asked the question, which was giving me a hard time. As always, thanks for everyones input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an `apply()` based solution that avoids the explicit for loop:

```
ff <- function(X) {X[which.max(X):length(X)] <- NA; X}
t(apply(Toy, 1, ff))
#      Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
# [1,]    3    3   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    8    7    7   NA   NA
# [3,]    2    3    5    2   NA
# [4,]    4   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [5,]    2    2   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

First we need to find the index of the maximum value for each row, and construct a vector with the indices of that index to the end of the row. We want to do this per row using an apply loop:

```
list_of_indices = apply(Toy, 1, function(x) which.max(x):ncol(Toy))
> list_of_indices
[[1]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 5

[[4]]
[1] 2 3 4 5

[[5]]
[1] 3 4 5
```

then we can loop of the list of indices and assign `NA` to the appropriate places in the `data.frame`:

```
for(i in seq_along(list_of_indices)) {
  Toy[i,list_of_indices[[i]]] <- NA
}
```

This leads to the desired result:

```
> Toy
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1    3    3   NA   NA   NA
2    8    7    7   NA   NA
3    2    3    5    2   NA
4    4   NA   NA   NA   NA
5    2    2   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

An lapply approach (Paul beat me by a minute):

```
inds <- lapply(apply(Toy, 1, which.max), function(x) x:ncol(Toy))
lapply(1:nrow(Toy), function(i) {Toy[i, inds[[i]]] <<- NA; return(Toy)})
Toy
```

Comment: +1, but I would prefer using a for loop to sticking to an `apply` based solution which needs global assignment (`<<-`).

Comment: @Paul I agree but because R is my first language my brain always goes to the apply solution rather than a loop.  If we benchmarked I bet yours would be a bit faster too since I believe the `lapply` is just a wrapper for a for loop.

Comment: Must use `apply`, must not use `for`, `for` is evil! ;)

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, I don't think`for` is evil---it has its place, I believe even in R, but it's not necessarily best in problems like this one. See [some benchmarks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449759/1270695) I did for a similar question. But Tyler is also correct: In this case `lapply` is not faster. I did some informal `system.time` tests with a 10000 row `data.frame` and the timings for one replacement were: Josh = 0.22 seconds, Paul = 6.15 seconds, and Tyler = 7.71 seconds.

Comment: @mrwab I think most people respond badly to `for` loops is because they often are an indicator for lack of R experience.

Comment: @mrwab any idea why Josh's solution is so much faster?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, no, but perhaps you shouldn't pay attention to me. According to Gavin, [`apply` is also evil](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5387022#5387022).